# Set a placeholder value to the field name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, placeholder

I was wondering if there was a way to set a placeholder value to the field name from the database similar to how the label is set?

So the db field named unit_price would display like this;

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the placeholder value to use the attribute name like this:

```
<%= f.number_field(:unit_price, :placeholder => :unit_price) %>
```

But just to clarify this value doesn't come from the database as much as it comes from the locale.  You could change it like so:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    models:
      object: "The Object"
    attributes:
      object:
        unit_price: "Unite Prices!"
```

But that would also change the label value.

Comment: If you weren't having to heal with i18n, is there any advantage to using a symbol over of a string?  I was actually hoping to find some sort of attribute specific variable so the code could be the same for each input.

Comment: Not really an advantage other than the possibility of being multilingual.  You might look at the various `simple_form` type gems available that have helper functions to do some of this for you.